# Ruby on Rails 3.1 assets:precompile and images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I can't get the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline precompilation to work in production mode. It always fails on images referenced within SCSS with an error like:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production 
  rake aborted!
  rails.png isn't precompiled
    (in /home/florian/AssetTest/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

But when I look in the public/assets directory, the image is there, so it is precompiled:

```
  $ ls public/assets | grep rails 
    rails-dd352fc2630e5f9aa5685ef1d7fe5997.png
```

The SCSS file in this case just contains some test code:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
 */

body {
   background: #ffffff image-url('rails.png') no-repeat 0 center;
}
```

If I don't use the image-url helper in SCSS, but just url('/assets/rails.png'), precompilation works fine, and a manifest.yml file is generated in public/assets.

The interesting thing is: if I change the SCSS back to image-url('rails.png') and run another precompilation, it still works (I guess because the image is now already listed in the manifest file).

What am I doing wrong here? I don't really want to disregard the helper methods (as using them is The Way You Should Do It, right?), and I definitely don't want to create the manifest file manually...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into the same problem myself.  This is apparently a bug in Rails 3.1.0, and will hopefully be fixed in short order...

In any event, in `production.rb`, you can try this:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

You likely have it set to `false`, which it *should* be.  However, having it set to `false` causes issues when you use asset helpers in SCSS as you're trying to do.  Setting that value to `true` seems to properly allow compilation while using those helpers.

Take a look at [this issue on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2765) for some details.

Comment: Just updated to Rails 3.1.1rc1 as suggested in the github issue, and it works :-)

Comment: This answer seems bad for this reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not