# config.assets.compile=true in Rails production, why not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, production-environment

The default Rails app installed by `rails new` has `config.assets.compile = false` in production.

And the ordinary way to do things is to run `rake assets:precompile` before deploying your app, to make sure all asset pipeline assets are compiled.

So what happens if I set `config.assets.compile = true` in production?

I wont' need to run `precompile` anymore. What I *believe* will happen is the first time an asset is requested, it will be compiled. This will be a performance hit that first time (and it means you generally need a js runtime in production to do it).  But other than these downsides, after the asset was lazily compiled, I *think* all subsequent access to that asset will have *no* performance hit, the app's performance will be *exactly the same* as with precompiled assets after this initial first-hit lazy compilation. **is this true?**

Is there anything I'm missing? Any other reasons not to set `config.assets.compile = true` in production?  If I've got a JS runtime in production, and am willing to take the tradeoff of degraded performance for the *first* access of an asset, in return for not having to run `precompile`, does this make sense?

Comment: Warning, older versions of sprockets contain a bug and if config.assets.compile is configured to true there is a risk of directory trasversal vulnerability ( https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability )

Comment: This is exactly how Stackoverflow is supposed to work. A well written question and a well written answer. I love you both op and @richard-hulse.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

I wrote that bit of the guide.

You definitely do not want to live compile in production.

When you have compile on, this is what happens:

Every request for a file in /assets is passed to Sprockets. On the *first* request for each and every asset it is compiled and cached in whatever Rails is using for cache (usually the filesystem).

On subsequent requests Sprockets receives the request and has to look up the fingerprinted filename, check that the file (image) or files(css and js) that make up the asset were not modified, and then if there is a cached version serve that.

That is *everything* in the assets folder *and* in any vendor/assets folders used by plugins.

That is a lot of overhead as, to be honest, the code is not optimized for speed.

This will have an impact on how fast asset go over the wire to the client, and will negatively impact the page load times of your site.

Compare with the default:

When assets are precompiled and compile is off, assets are compiled and fingerprinted to the `public/assets`. Sprockets returns a mapping table of the plain to fingerprinted filenames to Rails, and Rails writes this to the filesystem. The manifest file (YML in Rails 3 or JSON with a randomised name in Rails 4) is loaded into Memory by Rails at startup and cached for use by the asset helper methods.

This makes the generation of pages with the correct fingerprinted assets very fast, and the serving of the files themselves are web-server-from-the-filesystem fast. Both dramatically faster than live compiling.

To get the maximum advantage of the pipeline and fingerprinting, you need to set far-future headers on your web server, and enable gzip compression for js and css files. Sprockets writes   gzipped versions of assets which you can set your server to use, removing the need for it to do so for each request.

This get assets out to the client as fast as possible, and in the smallest size possible, speeding up client-side display of the pages, and reducing (with far-future header) requests.

So if you are live compiling it is:

1. Very slow
2. Lacks compression
3. Will impact render time of pages

Versus

1. As fast as possible
2. Compressed
3. Remove compression overheard from server (optionally).
4. Minimize render time of pages.

Edit: (Answer to follow up comment)

The pipeline *could* be changed to precompile on the first request but there are some major roadblocks to doing so. The first is that there has to be a lookup table for fingerprinted names or the helper methods are too slow. Under a compile-on-demand senario there would need to be some way to append to the lookup table as each new asset is compiled or requested.

Also, someone would have to pay the price of slow asset delivery for an unknown period of time until all the assets are compiled and in place.

The default, where the price of compiling everything is paid off-line at one time, does not impact public visitors and ensures that everything works before things go live.

The deal-breaker is that it adds a lot of complexity to production systems.

**[Edit, June 2015]** If you are reading this because you are looking for a solution for slow compile times during a deploy, then you could consider precompiling the assets locally. Information on this is in the [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation). This allows you to precompile locally only when there is a change, commit that, and then have a fast deploy with no precompile stage.

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted your answer. But now my question is, okay, it doens't do it now, but conceivably do you think the Asset Pipeline _could_ have a feature where it lazily compiles on first request, doing it exactly like precompile, including writing to ./public and updating the fingerprint manifest?

Comment: See above. Is this an issue because Capistrano doesn't work for you?

Comment: I do not use Capistrano. I have not needed to before, the added complexity was not worth it. Perhaps the asset pipeline is the straw that breaks the camels back and requires it. In your opinion, it is infeasible to manage Rails deploys with asset pipeline _without_ capistrano or similar?  It's a shame, for simple setups it used to be not a big problem to do it by hand.

Comment: You really do need Capistrano for Rails 3.1. The assets are compiled in a new public directory while your old app is still running. When the compile is done the new version is symlinked and the server restarted automatically.

Comment: "To get the maximum advantage of the pipeline and fingerprinting, you need to set far-future headers on your web server, and enable gzip compression for js and css files."--Could you please provide some instructions or links for how to do this?

Comment: Start with the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#server-configuration

Comment: Anyone knows how can I detect if files are precompiled?

Comment: [oh dear, the hidden price of using magick codes!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow:++"config.assets.compile"+"true")

Comment: Should  we set config.assets.compile = true OR  config.assets.compile = false OR  comment this line in production mode?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 7):

To have less overhead with Pre-compiling thing.

```
Precompile everything initially with these settings in production.rb
# Precompile *all* assets, except those that start with underscore
config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

you can then simply use images and stylesheets as as "/assets/stylesheet.css" in *.html.erb 
or "/assets/web.png"

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using Heroku:

If you deploy to Herkou, it will do the precompile for you automatically during the deploy if compiled assets are not included (i.e. `public/assets` not committed) so no need for `config.assets.compile = true`, or to commit the precompiled assets.

Heroku's docs are [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline). A [CDN](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-with-rails) is recommended to remove the load on the dyno resource.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be the same as precompiling, even after that first hit: because the files aren't written to the filesystem they can't be served directly by the web server. Some ruby code will always be involved, even if it just reads a cache entry.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that with `precompile=true`, the compiled assets WOULD be written to the file system. Are you sure? Let me check...

Comment: Bah, I think you're right -- they ARE written to the file system, but it looks like in `tmp/cache` rather than `public/assets`, so not a place that the web server can see, they're still going to be served by the rails app not the web server. blah. is that right, you think?

Comment: Correct. Won't be as fast as having the web server pick them right up. Might not matter if you put a cdn like cloudfront in front of your app

Answer (score 1):

Set `config.asset.compile = false`

Add to your Gemfile

`group :assets do
         gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
 end`

Install the bundle

Run `rake assets:precompile`

Then Start your server

Comment: As far as i have set `config.asset.compile = true in production.rb` file, because there's no pre-comple mechanism is added. Due to that every time we start server it takes too much time to load the page( When request hit both processing the request and compiling assets).

Now i included `turbo-sprockets-rails3` in Gemfile and run the command `rake assets:precompile` its compiles the assets priorly. Now i set `config.asset.compile = false in production.rb` and start the server, the page loading without any delay. ( Only processing the request without asset compilation )

Comment: worth saying that `turbo-sprockets-rails3` is only necessary on Ruby 3

Answer (score 0):

From the official [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> On the first request the assets are compiled and cached as outlined in development above, and the manifest names used in the helpers are altered to include the MD5 hash.
>
> Sprockets also sets the Cache-Control HTTP header to max-age=31536000. This signals all caches between your server and the client browser that this content (the file served) can be cached for 1 year. The effect of this is to reduce the number of requests for this asset from your server; the asset has a good chance of being in the local browser cache or some intermediate cache.
>
> This mode uses more memory, performs poorer than the default and is not recommended.

Also, precompile step is not trouble at all if you use [Capistrano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano) for your deploys. It takes care of it for you. You just run

```
cap deploy
```

or (depending on your setup)

```
cap production deploy
```

and you're all set. If you still don't use it, I highly recommend checking it out.

Comment: So do you think that language from the official guide agrees with me? I've seen that guide, I'm not quite sure if it means what I'm suggesting above, what do you think? That's my question.

Comment: Yes, you say basically the same thing. I suggest that you don't turn live compilation on.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is opening a directory traversal vulnerability - https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability