# config.assets.compile with therubyracer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

In my application.js I have this:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require script
```

in my gemfile, I read somewhere that I should put this if I want to 'live compile' the assets each time i deploy.

`gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'`

When i put this, i can run `cap deploy` and `cap deploy:assets:precompile` successfully.

I also read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not) that this is an extremely bad idea. So now im confused whether Im supposed to do this or not... When i dont put therubyracer in my gemfile i get an error when i deploy (below), even if i run assets:prcompile first before I deploy... but its my understanding if i DO use that this is a huge amount of overhead...?

`could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they're not the same thing, and I need to simply add the assets to environments/production.rb where its commented