# Live compilation in Rails production environment for runtime generated images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I'm just starting to deploy my Rails application which generates .png images at runtime (generated by graphviz) and there is no way I can precompile them.  Now, I'm trying to figure out this whole assets pipeline issue.

I read on the [config.assets.compile=true in Rails production, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not) that live compilation is terrible.  Is there any smart way I can handle these assets or will I have to bite the bullet and use live compilation?  I can have live compilation turned on only for these runtime generated images and use precompilation for all other assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put runtime generated images somewhere else, don't try to get them in the asset pipeline. For example I put uploaded images in a shared folder that's outside of the main rails app folder, and symlink it when I deploy (I use capistrano for deployment, and this is a pretty standard setup).

The asset pipeline is great for ensuring people get the right images / stylesheets / js when you deploy new files, but it doesn't seem appropriate for stuff that will be created at runtime.