# Images load slowly in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have developed a website using ruby 1.9.3 and deployed in on aws server through passenger. But my website takes time in loading.

I am using passenger in: `production mode`

I am worried because i reduced the size of images to 100kb even then they took time in loading due to which animation can't occur properly.

I have `assets precompile :true`
in production environment.

Is there any way to load images fast.
Please help i am new to ruby

Thanks & Regards
Rajat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using asset pipeline, then you need precompile assets using the rake task and deploy the application to production.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Refer to below links for more info
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not

Comment: I have already set  config.assets.compile = true in production.rb. So, what is use of rake assets:precompile?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing live compilation in production mode. Pls check the above mentioned stackoverflow question why it shouldn't be set to true.   config.assets.compile should be set to false and the assets should be precompiled while deployment.