# Rails : deploying first app - production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, production

I am very confused about this whole rails deploy thing. The confusion is that whilst developing the whole app it has been in `development` mode, which is fine. Now that I will deploy it, are there ammendments I need to make to files to ***change*** the rails app to `production` mode before deploying, or does deploying autmatically do this?

I guess what I am asking is how do I switch from one environment to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to change any files just set shell variable `RAILS_ENV=production` on your server

Comment: how exactly do I do that? in terminal?

Comment: yes. `export RAILS_ENV=production`. also I recomend you to not use rails s in production. Try passenger server(https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) or other

Comment: I run the command but get no confirmation etc. How do I know if it is done or not?

Comment: If your server restarts you will need to `export RAILS_ENV=production` again.  You should put this in one of your config files, like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.  Also I would recommend thin or unicorn instead of passenger.  Their is nothing wrong with running `rails s`, just know that it runs webrick.  You can always specify the server to run for instance you could just run this command `rails server thin -e production`, assuming you have thin in your Gemfile, this will start thin and put rails in production mode in one command.

Answer (score 2):

`rails server -e production` will put you in production mode.

ALSO...

By default rails 3.1 and later defer assets to the asset pipeline.  So you either need to run `rake assets:precompile` or turn on serving assets in `config/environments/production.rb`.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.compile = true
```

You also need to ensure that your production database is setup correctly in `config/database.yml`

Other than that you are good to go :)

If this is truly a production box you could also set an environment variable to 'production' as well. As explained by Anatoliy Kukul in another answer.

Comment: Hey mwoods79.  You definitely SHOULD NOT set config.assets.compile = true.  Use rake assets:precompile.  Consider changing your answer.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not

Comment: @Ben my answer still holds true. Whether it is a good idea or not is another conversation. After years of consulting I can think of at least 2 large enterprise applications that do this, and do this well. Both of those apps also set the `asset_host` to use a CDN. This is a great strategy. The first request compiles the asset and stores it in the CDN. All asset requests after that get served from the CDN. Works great.