# image_tag different on production versus development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using image_tag in Rails. Locally it resolves to /assets/image.img. On Heroku it resolves to /images/image.img.

I have the asset pipeline turned off (this project will eventually leave Rails).

How can I make local resolve the same as production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.assets.compile = true
...
```

This fixed my problem. I guess this has something to do with the pipeline being turned off. Any comments on this are appreciated to help my understanding.

Comment: I figured this was bad practice though, as the asset pipeline slows down a server, and thus should be turned off when a rails app is deployed to production.

Comment: I don't have any answer to this issue yet but yes, this answer is bad practice and will hit your apps performance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

what's your complete image_tag ?
does it use

```
image_tag(asset_path('image.img'))
```

, or

```
image_tag('image.img')
```

?

If you turned the asset pipeline off, I suggest you don't use the `asset_path` form.

Comment: They are like this: <%= image_tag "logo.png", size: '303x87' %>