# application.css.scss file not precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I have seen lots of posts regarding precompiled assets in rails, but I don't think I see one that is related to my specific problem.

My application is complaining that aplication.css.scss is not precompiled.

From what I understand, any *.scss file should be compiled in my rails application when i run:

`rake assets:precompile`

I even confirmed in my public/assets folder that I can see the compiled application.css file.

However, when I try to visit the first page of my application I get the following error:

```
Compiled application.css  (1002ms)  (pid 20298)
Started GET "/" for 10.20.1.162 at 2013-01-21 12:21:38 -0500
Processing by MyController#new as HTML
  Rendered business_searches/partials/_form.html.erb (16.6ms)
  Rendered business_searches/new.html.erb within layouts/application (45.6ms)
  Rendered commons/_documenthead.html.erb (34.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 139ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css.scss isn't precompiled):
    4: <meta charset="utf-8" />
    5:   <title>My Company Name | <%= @page_title || 'My Company Tagline' %></title>
    6:
    7:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application.css.scss", :media => "all" %>
    8:  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    9:
    10:
  app/views/commons/_documenthead.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_commons__documenthead_html_erb___1078677729313377561_30352020'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___646383708034639720_28260100'
```

I was able to fix the problem by setting the following variable in my `config/environments/production.rb` file:

`config.assets.compile = true`

But according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827757/1663931), that is not recommended.

Comment: What is in the `application.html.erb` line 7, `<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application.css.scss", :media => "all" %>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to keep your manifest file `application.css` just for managing css assets , and not to prefix it with `.scss` . The correct syntax for `application.html.erb` file is :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application", :media => "all" %>
```

If you've placed some styles in your 'application.css`, just create a new`css.scss`file in your`app/assets/stylesheets` and place them there .

Comment: Thanks! Changing to use the correct syntax in `application.html.erb` did the trick!

Comment: I am happy if it has helped you . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your scss file is having a compile time error. I am quite sure that if you replace it's contents with known valid ones, it will get compiled.

You may comment it and check if it compiles.

Always use 'application.CSS' as base CSS. 
Others should be separate.