# Why do I get this error in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just switched from development mode to production mode.

However, now it always show "Something went wrong" error.

I've tried

```
$ rails s -e production
```

and I accessed to the page. Then I got this error.  How can I make it work fine in production mode?

```
Processing by TopController#index as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_social.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered top/index.html.erb within layouts/application (276.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 549ms

ActionView::Template::Error (delete.js.coffee isn't precompiled):
    11:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" %>
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Sample::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
   config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5


end
```

I'm using Apache2 + Passenger

**httpd.conf**

```
.....
RailsEnv production
.....
```

Comment: Have you run the rake task to precompile your assets?

Comment: Yes I did `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I'm guessing that delete.js.coffee is a custom file you've added - could it be invalid in some way, preventing precompilation from working?

Comment: @StephenOrr Ahh, Yes I have some files like that beside delete.js.coffee. How can I make it up?

Comment: @StephenOrr I have few *.js.coffee, *.js, *.css, and *.css.erb like that. How can I make it up?

Comment: maybe try adding this line in production.rb: config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js *.coffee)

Comment: afterwards bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: @Jean-Paul Thanks:) You don't need *.css.erb?

Comment: @Jean-Paul and what about images? I added many images into my assets/images/

Comment: i guess add " *.png *.jpg ", but does that line in production.rb work for you? did you test it?

Comment: @Jean-Paul  Thanks.  what about *.css.erb?  I'm trying it right now. but it's taking forever to execute `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: It has been over 10 minutes since I did `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` :(

Comment: ahhh it still says `ActionView::Template::Error (delete.js.coffee isn't precompiled):`

Comment: config.assets.compile = true

Comment: @Jean-Paul Does this look okay?  `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.erb *.scss *.js *.coffee *.png *.jpg *.ico *.gif)`

Comment: looks good; change config.assets.compile to true

Comment: @Jean-Paul Thanks. Let me try and tell you in a min

Comment: @Jean-Paul so after doing this again `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, should I just restart server and everything should be fine?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Yes that was it Thanks:) could you please make an answer? config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.erb *.scss *.js *.coffee *.png *.jpg *.ico *.gif) was the right answer

Comment: did u change config.assets.compile = true or it remained the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in config/environments/production.rb

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.erb *.scss *.js *.coffee *.png *.jpg *.ico *.gif)
```

Answer (score 0):

[avoid to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not)

```
config.assets.compile = true #quick dirty way
```

just add all assets what you didn't include into application.js (application.css)
to production.rb like

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w(delete.js.coffee)
```

than precompile assets again and this error will disappear (if delete.js.coffee placed in app/assets/javascripts)

same with any other standalone asset files. you can store them in one folder and pass a folder into `config.assets.precompile`