# Getting Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have an image named pt_homepage_banner1.png.

I ran the task on production

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and it successfully placed the image file into public/assets folder and made and entry into manifest.yml

Still i am getting exception -

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError

fpt_homepage_banner1.png isn't precompiled
```

My production.rb settings are

```
 config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.assets.compile = false
```

Please answer what i am missing. if any clarification regarding the question, please ask

Thank you

Comment: Well, it looks like the filename got an 'f' prepended to it somewhere -- so unless that's just a typo, you might try tracking that down.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error,

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError b-error.png isn't precompiled.
```

In my app I am calling this image, but in my images/ folder it was not there. So I added it and precompiled it again, so that the file appeared in public/assets folder. But I still gets the  same error. So I know that Rails is somewhat stuck with this file, so what I did is I changed the b-error.png to 500.png and used another image and precompiled.

```
Now it Works!
```

Answer (score -5):

Set following in *config/environments/production.rb*

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend but this will cause performance issue     Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not

Comment: put your images in  app/assets/images not in public/

Comment: Yes! i did the same. It was after compilation of the task that images are put into public/assets/images