# Rails 4: Bootstrap-sass gem assets work on development but not on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I have a rails app that I developed on my local machine using the gem bootstrap-sass. It all worked fine in development, but when I deployed my app to the production server the glyphicons stopped working.

There's an error in the console that says:

```
 downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal 
 weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status 2147746065 
 source: http://mydomain.com/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

And indeed there is no such file, but the same file with an asset pipeline digest. So it seems to me the request to the asset pipeline file is broken and therefore tries to get the normal file? Or is my asset pipeline broken? Not really sure. And not really sure why it works on my local machine but not on the server.

Do I have to configure my production.rb differently?

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `config.assets.compile` to `true` is not the best solution, considering performance stuff.

You may want to try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and restart server.

Comment: For those who are getting the error: `You have already activated rake y.y.y, but your Gemfile requires rake x.x.x` make sure you run `bundle update rake` before running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by setting

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: That's actually a terrible idea... read more on why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not