# Rails: Heroku assets in vendor getting 404

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a javascript in the `vendors/assets/javascripts` folder, and I have this line of code:

```
<script src="assets/grid.js"></script>
```

in one of my `app/views` page.

This `grid.js` file (inside the vendors directory) works when I test it out in localhost, but when I precompile and push my application to heroku, it says:

```
GET http://www.domain.com/assets/grid.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is this occurring?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`javascript_include_tag`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers) instead and that should work

```
<%= javascript_include_tag("grid.js") %>
```

In production I believe that the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) adds a hash onto the name of `grid.js` for fingerprinting (Section 1.2 of that documentation) so you can't use that path `<script src="assets/grid.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm still getting an error, but this time it says that : `ActionView::Template::Error (grid.js isn't precompiled)` which is weird because I did `rake assets:precompile` and also `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Try putting `config.assets.precompile += ['grid.js']` in your `config/application.rb` file

Comment: hmm i tried this at first, but it didn't work. so then I added this and changed `config.assets.compress = false` to `true`. Does this sound the right thing to do as well?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3? Try `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in your `config/application.rb`, more on that in the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-3-asset-pipeline)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using rails 3. I do have it set on false also. Setting my `config.assets.compress = true` made it work. Was this not the correct solution to do so?

Comment: Check out this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not), it says it slows down the site, honestly, I'm not sure why your previous attempts were not working

Comment: I'm not sure either, but thanks for your help. I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried: Set `config.assets.compress = true` in my `config/environments/production.rb` and all was fine, but it is a bad practice and gain bad performance. Yo can see this for more details [config.assets.compile=true in Rails production, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not)

My solution:
Run in your local project `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and push all the files generated in public/assent/ in your github repo and deploy in heruko. Yo can read this for more details https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally