# Rails assets paths are not compiling correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, asset-pipeline, assets, sprockets

I think I have configured my asset path correctly but for example my stylesheet is not rendering

i.e: style.css is located in:

/app/assets/sheetsheets/style.css

and in the browser it rendered:

/app/assets/style.css

using the link: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "style", :media => "all" %>`

so my stylesheet doesn't load.

production environment: config/environments/production.rb

```
Cms::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end'
```

Hopefully I'm overlooking something really simple here but please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to precompile your assets on production:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

also set

`config.assets.compile` to `false`, you [do not want that to be true on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not).

Comment: Thank you for this Tirdadc, bundle exec rake worked perfectly, but when I reconfigured config.assets.complie to false I get this error: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled) I'm going to read up on this!