# Override capistrano deploy:assets:precompile command in rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

I am making use of rubber for deploying to an amazon ec2 server. I want to override the deploy:assets:precompile task to make it compile locally. I am adding the task in the deploy.rb file but it doesn't seem to be using that.
Here is the gist for the deploy file: https://gist.github.com/bipinshashi/1952e36f9b6bab1c64f4

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the issue - Had to comment out

> load 'deploy/assets'

in deploy.rb and add the code within the "if Rubber::Util.has_asset_pipeline?" block. Here is a gist with the correct code: https://gist.github.com/bipinshashi/703792fa31a5fb0f46f3

Comment: This definitely got me over the hump of deploying assets when running the Rubber QuickStart manual