# Rails Asset Pipeline - Not compiling manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, precompile

I am building my blog and its admin section is significantly different from the rest of the site. So I decided to have separate manifests as per what I understand in the [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) documentation.

#### Problem:

The admin section works as expected with the styles applied properly. But in production it doesn't. I have run `rake assets:precompile` and it only generates one version which is **application-[blah].js**. and not a **admin_lite-[blah].js**

What could I be doing wrong? Help is greatly appreciated.

#### More information

- app/assets/stylesheets/admin_lite.css
- <%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin_lte", media: 'all' %>
  \
- app/assets/javascripts/admin_lite.js
- <%= javascript_include_tag "admin_lte" %>
- Added initilizer (config/intilizers/assets.rb) `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin_lite.js', 'admin_lite.css']`
- ran `RAILS_ENV bin/rake assets:precompile
- Only generates some thing like applicaiton-[signature].js && application-[signature].css
- The css and js links in the admin section is as /stylesheets/admin_lite.css /javascripts/admin_lite.css ( not the format it is for application-* varients which have a signature ).

#### The css output

```
<link href="/stylesheets/admin_lte.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/javascripts/admin_lte.js"></script>
```

#### Updates

- added `config.assets.precompile += ['admin_lite.js', 'admin_lite.css']` to `config/environments/production.rb` (and also `development.rb` to test)
- added `config.assets.precompile += ['admin_lite.js', 'admin_lite.css']` to `application.rb`

with no success

#### Fix / Resolved

The error was a typo, where I had used the wrong file name and thus it was not compiled. So, if you...

- run `rake assets:precompile`
- `application.css` compiles but not your custom manifest (ex: admin.css)
- **Check the spelling**
- I really wish it to have raised an exception.

Comment: You want to add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin_lite.js', 'admin_lite.css']` to `config/environments/production.rb` this is what rails will call in precompiling.

Comment: Does make sense, let me try. I was following the link I posted about asset pipeline, it says to have an internalize named assets.rb (need to update question).

Comment: No it didn't work. I added it to development as well and ran precompile, only has application- varients.

Comment: If an asset is missed, rails can fall back. In your production.rb is the line 'config.assets.compile = true'

Comment: Also, I don't know how you're deploying; but just to make sure, are you restarting the rails app in production?

Comment: Is it _lite or _lte? Your code seems to be using both

Comment: @FrederickCheung - You are my guardian angel. It worked when I change `little` to `lte`. Do add it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RussellKompinski Does `config.assets.compile = true` act as a fallback? Meaning which if the assets are not compiled, it will use run time compile it? Thanks for the info

Comment: Yea it does, but after researching I learned that it's best not to, and here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not - So it looks like I will stop doing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the name of the manifest you are asking it to precompile doesn't match the setting - try changing `lite` to `lte`

Answer (score 1):

I've found (with Rails 4.1.6, at least), that the file extension used in the config.assets.precompile and the javascript_include_tag are of vital importance.

I recently added the following to my production.rb:

```
  config.assets.precompile += %w(google/infobox.js)
```

And in the HAML file that would use the asset I had:

```
=javascript_include_tag "google/infobox"
```

Of course, this works like a charm in development mode!

So, I promote the code to production and when I ran `rake assets:precompile` on the server I see the precompiled file get created:

```
Writing public/assets/google/infobox-85c3151833c8f22f374f4fb25b7f917f.js
```

Awesome!

But alas no...

Long story short, **I had to explicitly add the ".js" extension** into javascript_include_tag to be:

```
=javascript_include_tag "google/infobox.js"
```

Hope this saves somebody some time in the future.

Also hope that somebody isn't me stumbling upon my own answer the next time it happens to me and I can't remember why it happened.