# Rails 4 not requesting fingerprinted asset in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I've just deployed a Rails 4.1.1 app to a VPS. Running Ruby 2 and Passenger.

My application is not making requests to the fingerprinted version of the asset files. In my `application.html.erb` I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "slick" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
```

Generating output html of:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/stylesheets/slick.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/javascripts/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Relevant config is:

**production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/modernizr.js slick.css )
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are not precompiling assets. In your production.rb make following change

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: That directive is where you want Sprockets to compile assets on the fly in production and [that is not good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not). I am precompiling and MD5 fingerprinted assets are in my public/assets directory.