# Rails 4: Setting config.assets.compile to false deactivates whole Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The CSS and Javascripts in my Rails 4 app fails to load on production, but was successful in staging. The only difference between between `config/environments/staging.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb` is this line:

`config.assets.compile = true` on staging, and

`config.assets.compile = false` on production.

In both staging and production, I do `rake assets:precompile` on during deployment. Yes, the fingerprinted assets are happily situated at `public/assets`

It is tempting to just raise my hand, cry "What the heck, I still have other things to code", and [just set config.assets.compile = true on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not), but as I understand this enables Live Compilation, which dynamically compiles Sass and CoffeeScripts, and I do NOT want that kind of performance tax on our live site.

However, setting `config.assets.compile = false` in production does NOT generate the proper fingerprinted URL to point to the precompiled assets properly.

In staging, my application.css is happily pointed to `https://staging.example.com/assets/application-8b1ca5ff4a98a7b28b0e932fe7412421.css`. Which is well and good and bliss and wonderful.

In production, it frustratingly points at `https://www.example.com/stylesheets/application.css`

How do I then I still use Assets Pipeline (Sprockets) without Live Compilation on production? Anybody who could help me before I run out of hair would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer. Will leave my findings here for future visitors.

It's a timing issue in my deployment system (Amazon OpsWorks), where the code is deployed, *then* `assets:precompile`d. The first deployment does not work. The second does however. The system does not `assets:precompile` when the md5sum of all `app/assets` does not change.

Which leads me to conclude the following

if `config.assets.compile = false`

**Rails looks for `public/assets/manifest-md5hash.json`. If it exists, it gives the `/assets/application-md5hash.css` fingerprinted version. If it does not exist, it gives the `/stylesheets/application.css` version.**