# rails assets precompile error with a js with variable definitions with a -. works on one computer and in other not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and getting this error

```
...somefile.js
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (-) (line: 3, col: 9, pos: 11)
```

This is the content of that line:

```
var color-green="#27cebc";
```

I guess the problem is because the variable name includes a `-`. However using the same ruby version on local computer with same command, it's able to process correctly without the error:

On my local computer:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
```

And it was able to process the offending file without problems, and generated this file:

```
public/assets/js/some=file-68c9a5f2e1f2216c5d3d2b9fcd7741155113425f7f46f18187ad5b98e1a11092.js

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.1p85
$ gem list | grep js
execjs (2.5.2)
```

I tried commenting the line out and it process all the files succesfully, but I dont understand why on local it works with that line, and in the server doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is assets not compile in development mode. but when you start in production mode its need to compile first.

you can see difference between `development.rb` and `production.rb` in environment folder.

you can explore more here.

[config.assets.compile=true in Rails production, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not)

Comment: I ran this on local `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and it were able to process all assets including the offending one, is the same command ran on the server

Comment: you mean to say you run command on local and its execute without error but its throw error with same code on server.

Answer (score 0):

You were able to use it locally because you weren't doing the precompilation/preprocessing locally.

However, I doubt if it really worked locally as JS would have thrown an exception of `Unexpected token -`, because the interpretation of the line is `color minus green`, as you cannot use `-` in the name of a variable

Comment: I ran this on local `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and it were able to process all assets including the offending one, is the same command ran on the server