# Rails 5 app. Asset pipelining and precompilation with heroku not showing up images from js.jsx files

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I am almost done with upgrading my Rails3 app to Rails5; But I am facing a problem with assets pipelining and precompiling. We're using cdn as asset host.Now, What happens is that when I set config.assets.precompile to false in staging environment, the app doesn't load images from js.jsx files. At other places, the app is fetching the static assets (js,css,images) from the asset_host link that I've provided. But in some specific javascript files, The images is being pointed out to my app's domain like app.my_domain.com/assets/my_image.png,And it is giving 404 not found error.
In javascript, the code is something like

`return (
<img src="/assets/my_image.png"></img>
)`

Since this is a js file, I cannot use asset_path helper method here. 
How to resolve this issue ?

PS: setting config.assets.precompile to true loads the image from app.my_domain.com/assets/my_image.png, but that's not what I want because of this. [config.assets.compile=true in Rails production, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not#8827757)

Any help with this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer after some research. I changed the name of the file to js.jsx.erb and accordingly used asset_path helper method which rails provide.

`return (
<img src = "asset_path 'my_image.png'"/>
)`

It works.