# All assets are not loading in production envirnoment rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Anything works fine while I run my server using `rails s`, but while I run the server in production mode it looks like:[without stylesheets and other assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ6xR.png). What I have to do to solve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `production.rb` set

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then run the server like this

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

Comment: Enabling only `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` worked for me. Also enabling `config.assets.compile = true`  is not recommended in the production environment. Ref: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545262/rails-5-assets-not-loading-in-production)

Answer (score 0):

Did you precompile your assets? Try running locally:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

A `public/assets` directory will be created and then commit changes to your repository.
The assets should now be detected on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with an example how you are linking to CSS and JS files? It should look like this ( this is in .haml not .erb)

`= stylesheet_link_tag    'default/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
 = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true`

Comment: Actually, I have that on my .erb file, but there is no .haml file is there.