# RoR App: “The asset 'application.css' is not present in the asset pipeline”

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

Info:
Rails 6.1.4
Ruby 3.0.1
PostgreSQL 9.6
NodeJS 11.15.0
Yarn 1.22.5

when I start my APP I always got the same error:
[image]

I've tried all I saw in others posts but I can´t resolve this problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: is there `application.css` on your `app/assets/stylesheets` ?

Comment: Check your `application.css` load or not using url: `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css`

Comment: Yes, `application.css` is in app/assets/stylesheets but I can't access using the url. I get this error when I try to access: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Answer (score 0):

In `config/environments/production.rb` I added the following line:

```
# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
```

also I checked the following line:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

With this configuration I can start my APP.

Comment: the assets should be precompiled in the production environment. Here is the explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827757/4492997

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to do the following on the server

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```