How do I make local development in rails not use cached assets?
I am having an issue with compilation of assets in my local development - they are no longer found.  I am not sure how it came about, but if I run rails assets:precompile then the latest of my javascript and css is available.  When attempting to reset to have rails compile assets on the fly, I did the following:
I ran rails assets:clobber
I verified in my environment/development.rb that I had the following configs (basically have been trawling random overflow posts and trying all ways to turn off caching):
config.assets.compile = true
config.cache_classes = false
config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = false
config.cache_store = :null_store

When I view the chrome debugger console, I see this error:
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

And I see in the network requests the following request
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/assets/application-4715fb6ab7ed9d0e2856431daf6257fbe7f65970d0fdde5c07720f54c8b9258c.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers:
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 0
location: /
server-timing: sql.active_record;dur=0.24, instantiation.active_record;dur=0.02
x-request-id: 1422221c-a466-459d-9793-e34158e4782d
x-runtime: 0.041250

I also found that if I change a css file and restart the server, the hash from application-4715fb6ab7ed9d0e2856431daf6257fbe7f65970d0fdde5c07720f54c8b9258c.css will change.  So I'm assuming that for some reason rails is continues to look for the precompiled version and does not compile?
I have also tried config.assets.digest = false which made the network request look for http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css which was also not found.
some relevant files
manifest.js
//= link_tree ../builds
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets/administrate .css
//= link administrate-field-active_storage/application.css

 assets/builds:
application.css | application.css.map | application.js | application.js.map

and when I start my local server, I see
$ tailwindcss --postcss --minify -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --watch
in the logs

You don't need to compile your assets in development. Either Sprockets or Propshaft and your Rails app are able to resolve every asset in your app. Precompilation is for production only. It will fingerprint the asset (add a hash) and depending of your asset pipeline toll will minify and compress (with Propshaft the minification and compression into GZ and Brotli is left to the user, mostly through node / rake task).

So just clobber your assets, or remove the "public/assets" folder from your app and your assets should be found. (be careful to not remove the "public" folder all together as it contains your robots.txt file, your favicon, some 404.html etc .. beside /assets folder)

yes, so I have been running rails assets:clobber and also manually ensuring that my public/assets folder is totally deleted.  This has not fixed the problem :(.  I also even created a new folder and re downloaded the repo, to ensure that somehow there was no hidden cache.  This new download still had the same issue.

does tailwind actually compile successfully? you should have app/assets/builds/application.css file present.

Should be config.assets.compile = false or am I missing something

hey @Alex, yes I do have an app/assets/builds/application.css file present.
@dbugger, config.assets.compile = true I believe is the standard for local development, as it instructs rails to compile (not the same as precompile).  See section https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation

additional information:
When I add config.assets.debug = true and I run bin/rake assets:precompile then things do NOT work and the files are not found :thinking

@user1409045 did you read those docs? "On the first request the assets are compiled and cached...Sprockets also sets the Cache-Control HTTP header to max-age=31536000. This signals all caches between your server and the client browser that this content (the file served) can be cached for 1 year. The effect of this is to reduce the number of requests for this asset from your server; the asset has a good chance of being in the local browser cache or some intermediate cache." This appears to be the exact opposite of *"How do I make local development in rails not use cached assets?"

Hey engineersmnky, thanks for the question.  The thing is, even with an incognito browser, there is no initial compilation of the assets when I do not precompile.  That is, I do not even see an initial cache.  Further, based on this other stack overflow answer I was under the impression that changed files would invalidate the cache on next request https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827757 when using the aforementioned config option (sorry on mobile so can't link well)

I don't recall trying to do config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets" so I will try that tomorrow
