# ActionView::Template::Error (rails.png isn't precompiled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-11.10, precompile

I am getting the page "We're sorry, but something went wrong, when I try to load my rails application.  When I run

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (rails.png isn't precompiled)
```

I have run

```
 RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

from the current directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer here

[Ruby on Rails 3.1 assets:precompile and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647691/ruby-on-rails-3-1-assetsprecompile-and-images)

change config.assets.compile = false to config.assets.compile = true in the production.rb file in the /current/config/environments